# How to add a postgresql jdbc driver to intellij?

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I'm trying to add a driver, and this page tells me to open `View | Tool Windows | Database` https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-data-sources.html

But there is no such tool window. See picture

[image]

I tried Alt-3 since that option is missing in the menu, but nothing happens.

How do I add the postgresql driver from Intellij? I already have the mysql driver.

IntelliJ version: IntelliJ IDA 2020.2.1 Community edition

Comment: What is your IntelliJ version ?

Comment: @BenjaminD Forgot to mention that. Edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/#choose-your-edition), the Community edition does not include the database tool.

You'll need the Ultimate edition for that.

Then, if you want to just add the library to your project, you can select the project root in IntelliJ, hit F4. Go to Project settings ==> Libraries

Hit the + icon and choose Java.

Then, browse to your driver jar file and select it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what I could do instead?

Comment: What is your need exactly ? If you need the database tool, you should get the Ultimate edition. If not, you can use various other tools.

Comment: What I need is to install the postgresql jdbc driver

Comment: There are different things. In Intellij, the driver allows you to acces the database and to query it within your IDE. For what I understand, this is not your need. If you need to add the jdbc driver to your project in order to use it, then you must add the jar to your project manually or use a dependancy manager like Gradle or Maven.

Comment: TBH, I'm not completely sure. I'm not experienced with Java. I have a project. In that, I have a few classes that are supposed to access a postgres database on localhost. Now I want to use JUnit to create a test in which the database is accessed

Comment: Maybe I should reword the whole question?

Comment: If you want, I can help, but maybe not in the comments. How can we start a chat ? (I'm kinda new in here).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220917/discussion-between-klutt-and-benjamind).

Answer (score 2):

If you use Ubuntu.

And the driver cannot be downloaded for some reasons.

And you want manually install the driver then you can download `postgreSQL` driver from here https://jdbc.postgresql.org/.

Then copy it into `PHPStorm` config folder using this this path.

`/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2023.1/jdbc-drivers`

[image]

After the operation you should get successful connection with your database.

[image]